# Link Scraping with requests, bs4. Getting Warning: unresponsive script

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, komodo

Im trying to collect all links from a webpage using requests, Beautifulsoup4 and SoupStrainer in Python3.3. For writing my code im using Komodo Edit 8.0 and also let my scripts run in Komodo Edit. So far everything works fine but on some webpages it occurs that im getting a popup with the following Warning

```
Warning unresponsive script

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script
now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: viewbufferbase:797
```

Then i can chose if i want to continue or stop the script.

Here a little code snippet:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(adress, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True))
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):

        #some code

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```

My question is what is causing this error. Is it my python script that is taking too long on a webpage or is it a script on the webpage im scraping? I cant think of the latter because technically im not executing the scripts on the page right?
Or can it maybe be my bad internet-connection?

Oh and another little question, with the above code snippet am im downloading pictures or just the plain html-code? Because sometimes when i look into my connection status for me its way too much data that im receiving just for requesting plain html code?
If so, how can I avoid downloading such stuff and how is it possible in general to avoid downloads with requests, because sometimes it can be that my program ends on a download page.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you go any deeper than the first level in the website's graph?

Comment: Technically im checking just one page at a time. If one page is finished it goes on with checking another found link.

Comment: What i meant is if during visiting each site are you gathering links on them and processing them later so that you go deeper and deeper?

Comment: Oh, yes im doing exactly that. I have a list that starts with just one link, and then it adds all found links to the list. Just internal of course.

Comment: The issue might be either long loading times of a site, or a cycle in your website links' graph - i.e. page1 (Main Page) has link to page2 (Terms of Service) which in turn has link to page1. You could try [this snippet](http://pastebin.com/5it8Nph7) to see how long it takes to get a response from a website (snippet usage included).

Comment: Thanks i will try this snippet. The second case is not possible, so i guess it only occurs if it takes too long to completely load the page? So it can be a server issue or also my connection can be too slow. Do you know if theres a possibility to let my skript run as long as need. I mean is it an issue of the request module, or of komodo? I think i will try running it in the python console. But thanks for your effort!

Comment: The message is caused by `komodo` - `requests` will throw a timeout exception if the connection takes too long to complete.

Comment: Ah ok perfect then! Thx, if you want write a short answer just saying look in comments, that i can accept that and the case is solved. Oh and maybe you can give me a small hint for my last questions in the initial post? thx alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be either long loading times of a site, or a cycle in your website links' graph - i.e. page1 (Main Page) has link to page2 (Terms of Service) which in turn has link to page1. You could try [this snippet](http://pastebin.com/5it8Nph7) to see how long it takes to get a response from a website (snippet usage included).

Regarding your last question:

I'm pretty sure `requests` doesn't parse your response's content (except for `.json()` method). What you might be experiencing is a link to a resource, like `<a href="http://www.example.com/very_big_file.exe">Free Cookies!</a>` which you script would visit. `requests` have mechanics to counter such case, see [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced.html#body-content-workflow) for reference. Moreover, the aforementioned technique allows checking `Content-Type` header to make sure you're downloading pages you're interested in.